# Where's javax.servlet?

Tags: java, servlets

I have `jdk1.6.0_13` installed, but when I try to find a `javax.servlet` package, or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> in Eclipse after `Servlet` I cannot get anything. Where can I download this package, and why isn't it included in standard distribution for developers?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

`javax.servlet` is a package that's part of Java EE (Java Enterprise Edition). You've got the JDK for Java SE (Java Standard Edition).

You could use [the Java EE SDK](http://java.sun.com/javaee/downloads/?intcmp=1282) for example.

Alternatively simple servlet containers such as [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) also come with this API (look for `servlet-api.jar`).

Answer (score 22):

A bit more detail to Joachim Sauer's answer:

On Ubuntu at least, the metapackage `tomcat6` depends on metapackage `tomcat6-common` (and others), which depends on metapackage `libtomcat6-java`, which depends on package **`libservlet2.5-java`** (and others). It contains, among others, the files `/usr/share/java/servlet-api-2.5.jar` and `/usr/share/java/jsp-api-2.1.jar`, which are the servlet and JSP libraries you need. So if you've installed Tomcat 6 through apt-get or the Ubuntu Software Centre, you already have the libraries; all that's left is to get Tomcat to use them in your project.

Place libraries `/usr/share/java/servlet-api-2.5.jar` and `/usr/share/java/jsp-api-2.1.jar` on the class path like this:

- For all projects, by configuring Eclipse by selecting Window ->
  Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs, then selecting the JRE you're
  using, pressing Edit, then pressing Add External JARs, and then by
  selecting the files from the locations given above.
- For just one
  project, by right-clicking on the project in the Project Explorer
  pane, then selecting Properties -> Java Build Path, and then pressing
  Add External JARs, and then by selecting the files from the locations
  given above.

Further note 1: These are the correct versions of those libraries for use with Tomcat 6; for the other Tomcat versions, see the table on page http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html, though I would suppose each Tomcat version includes the versions of these libraries that are appropriate for it.

Further note 2: Package `libservlet2.5-java`'s description (`dpkg-query -s libservlet2.5-java`) says: 'Apache Tomcat implements the **Java Servlet and the JavaServer Pages (JSP)** specifications from Sun Microsystems, and provides a "pure Java" HTTP web server environment for Java code to run. This package contains the Java Servlet and JSP library.'

Comment: +1 Thankyou for taking the time to add to this old question. I'm troubleshooting some legacy software and this answer was tremendously helpful!

Answer (score 8):

Have you instaled the [J2EE](http://java.sun.com/javaee/)? If you installed just de standard (J2SE) it won´t find.

Answer (score 4):

The normal procedure with Eclipse and Java EE webapplications is to install a servlet container (Tomcat, Jetty, etc) or application server (Glassfish (which is bundled in the "Sun Java EE" download), JBoss AS, WebSphere, Weblogic, etc) and integrate it in Eclipse using a (builtin) plugin in the *Servers* view.

During the creation wizard of a new *Dynamic Web Project*, you can then pick the integrated server from the list. If you happen to have an existing *Dynamic Web Project* without a server or want to change the associated one, then you need to modify it in the *Targeted Rutimes* section of the project's properties.

Either way, Eclipse will automatically place the necessary server-specific libraries in the project's classpath (buildpath).

You should absolutely in **no way** extract and copy server-specific libraries into `/WEB-INF/lib` or even worse the `JRE/lib` yourself, to "fix" the compilation errors in Eclipse. It would make your webapplication tied to a specific server and thus completely unportable.

Answer (score 2):

If you've got the Java EE JDK with Glassfish, it's in glassfish3/glassfish/modules/javax.servlet-api.jar.

Answer (score 0):

those classes are usually part of servlet.jar 
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/wsit/Downloadservletjar.htm