# javax.servlet.* cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

I am running ubuntu 14.04 and eclipse Kepler (with java ee modules preloaded) , I am developing Dynamic Web App for first time, it always says javax.servlet.xyz cannot be resolved to a type please help I am including a screen snapshot for my error page!

[image: System Snapshot]

Comment: Have you added `servlet-api.jar` to your eclipse's build path?

Comment: no I haven't please can you explain how to do it in ubuntu I don't even know where is Tomcat lib

Comment: @Creator check second answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860022/wheres-javax-servlet

Comment: You will get that in Server-> Runtime Configuration preferences window.

Comment: @PradeepSimha- I don't get a runtime config option

Comment: @I-LOVE-2-REVIVE- I have installed the java EE already

Comment: @Creator read the second answer not the first. It will tell you how to add to your class path

Comment: I have read second answer and done everything according to it but I got following error msg  Access restriction: The type ServletException is not accessible due to restriction on required library /usr/share/
 java/servlet-api-3.0.jar

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Only two things are required in Eclipse for this:

**One**

In Eclipse, Window -> Preferences -> Server -> Runtime Environment
Specify your Web Server or Application Server path, by adding a "New Server Runtime Environment".

***Update***

Initially, there are only few Server Runtime Environments available with Eclipse like:

1. Apache
2. Basic
3. ObjectWeb

On an additional note, you can add more Server Adapters using the link *`Download additional server adapters`* in *Server Runtime Environments* dialog screen.

[image: Server Runtime ENvironment List in Eclipse Preferences]

**Two**

In Project Properties (Right Click on Project -> Properties), in Java Build Path, add Library `"Server Runtime"`.
On adding Server Runtime to Project Library will add `servlet-api.jar` and `jsp-api.jar` jars to project dependencies.

[image: Add Server Runtime Library to Project]

Comment: that was exactly what i need thanx you were like a saviour

Comment: by the way if this was automated it would be easier...why is eclipse so much descriptive while using??

Comment: I have given the answer considering Eclipse IDE, there might be different options available with other IDE's, which I am not aware much. So I mentioned that this answer is considering the Eclipse IDE.
And one more point, the screenshot attached with the question is looks like to be a screenshot of Eclipse IDE.